# how to index array in matlab for proper matrix

Tags: matlab

i am new in matlab and trying to make like this:

```
>>matdup(1,2,2)
ans = 1 1

      1 1
```

but my code output is different:

```
function m = matdup( input,row,col )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    for i = 1:row
        for j = 1:col
            m{i, j}= input;
        end
    end

end
```

but this is giving me like this

```
[1] [1]
[1] [1]
```

??? any idea how to index properply??? as this is showing each separate matrix

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing your old question.

Comment: ok sorry. i will. it is happend before and they asked me dont post new question if you have any question related. i am really sorry for your key time wastage.

Comment: Well I don't really see a question here, it looks like a copy-paste of the command window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `()`(array data index) instead `{}` (cell data index)

```
function m = matdup( input,row,col )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
    for i = 1:row
        for j = 1:col
            m(i, j)= input;
        end
    end

end
```

but you can also use:

```
>> ones(2)

ans =

     1     1
     1     1
```

or

```
>> ones(row,col).*input
```

to replicate your desired behavior.

```
>> ones(3,2).*5

ans =

     5     5
     5     5
     5     5
```

Comment: thanks. but i found another problem that is when i write >>matdup([1 2],3,4) or somthing like this it gives me error dimension mismatch. any idea???

Comment: what would be your disired output for this? something like this `>> a=ones(3,4,2); a(:,:,2)=a(:,:,2).*2; a`

Comment: no no i want this to happen through my code. that is write >>matdup([1 2],3,4)  and output shd be : 1 2